# Avoiding conditional joins by model design

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm designing my db and am trying to figure out the best way to avoid conditional joins in the future. I've read articles that show the conditional joins and it is definitely something I want to avoid if possible.

I have a `CHECK` table, and `CHECK` will store some data (amount, date, etc). I also have 3 'other' tables, `VENDOR`, `VENDOR_DEPT`, `VENDOR_ACCOUNT` of which `VENDOR_ACCOUNT` has a fk to `VENDOR_DEPT`, and `VENDOR_DEPT` has an fk to `VENDOR`.

My issue is this: how do I design my model so that CHECK can be either assigned to `VENDOR`, `VENDOR_DEPT` or `VENDOR_ACCOUNT` without having `vend_id`, `vendacct_id` and `venddept_id` in my `CHECK` table or having a VENDOR_CHECK table that has columns `check_id` ,`vendor_level`, `join_id`.... (hopefully you get the picture)

Is there a cleaner way? BTW, I'm using MYSQL but I'd like the solution to work on other platforms as well.

Since I'm at the model design phase, I'm open to all suggestions including redesigning these tables of course :)

Comment: Why wouldn't the Check always be associated with a Vendor Account, from which you can derive the department and vendor?

Comment: because I want the user to be able to add the check to the entire vendor, rather than a specific department if need be. Some vendors will be so small a dept or acct may not exist... Imagine different table names: Project - Assignment - Task (and imagine they are in a hierarchy: Proj has 0 or more Assignments and Assign has 0 or more Tasks) if I had a 'cost' item that I wanted to attribute to the Project, I want it seen differently than a cost at the Task level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to implement a "one-of" relationship in SQL.  This type of relationship can be a bit challenging.  I suppose the "relational" way to solve it is to say that you really have a CHECK_ENTITY, and this entity can be one of the three types.  That seems unnecessarily cumbersome, however.

One suggestion is to have the three different columns in the table.  My guess is that you will often want to be using vend_id for reporting purposes.  Simply populate the appropriate ones for a given CHECK.

Yes, your data is then denormalized, because vend_id would be both in the CHECK table and in the VEND_ACCT table.  If accounts and departments change, then this captures the relationship at the time of the CHECK, which may be what you want.

An alternative option is to have a dummy account that means "the entire vendor".  Then just use this value to mean the entire vendor.  Similarly, you would need accounts for each department.

This approach requires some discipline.  It is tempting to set up a vendor hierarchy, with any possible depth, with a link back the parent (accounts --> departments --> vendors, so why not generalize it?).  SQL is even worse at hierarchical queries than at one-of relationships.  By "worse", I mean that the methods for handling such queries are very database-dependent.

Comment: Gordon, fantastic response. Thank you! I like the dummy account idea, of course this still means that either I'll need to make more than a single call to the db, or I'll have to make use of outer joins to get my data.